# Using Meteor (port3000) and running index.html from IDE not output

Tags: meteor, ide, localhost, ports

I am Just starting to learn meteor using the official meteor tutorial.

All of this easy to understand.  It works.

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
meteor create simple-todos
cd simple-todos
meteor

"Open your web browser and go to http://localhost:3000 to see the app running."
```

Then I begin the tutorial.

I use Netbeans 8.0 and I am current with updates.

On a mac.

My question has to do with the Ports.

I have been coding MAMP, MEAN, etc. etc. so I am a little confused   because they all use specific ports.
8000 8383 8888 3000

In Netbeans, I usually have to start like this:

```
new > project > html > <nameOfProject>
```

It creates this structure inside of Netbeans IDE.

It creates it within this directory. See images.

This is by default.

```
Project Location: /Application/MAMP/htdocs
```

[image: netbeansIDE_1]

[image: netbeansIDE_2]

This directory runs on port 8888 - I think.
Which Port ?  I used to know how to check this and forget.

Within the Netbeans Project Named Meteor1

I needed to Create these files !

```
file > new > simple-todos.js
file > new > simple-todos.css
file > new > simple-todos.html
```

Then I copy the code from the tutorial into these files.

Note.  Do you see the IDE alerts in the margins ?

[image: meteorNetbeans_6]

When I

```
run > simple-todos.html
```

The browser outputs this:

[image: meteorNetbeans_5]

when I change url: localhost:3000
it says,

```
"This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Then I recalled I needed to launch meteor.
See the screenshot about how I navigated inside of the directory 
and ran

```
meteor
```

It says,

```
"You are not in a Meteor Project"
```

[image: meteorNetbeans_5]

So I am STUCK.

Rather than further explain what I understand and do not understand, I am missing something and I am certain that this will be easy to explain to me.

Thanks.

Comment: You get the error message, because the hidden directory `.meteor` is missing in your `public_html`. You need to initialize your Meteor project with `meteor create public_html`.

Comment: @matthias Eckhart 4 thanks.  Yes. That came to mind that I needed to drill into that directory

Answer (score 1):

You should create a project by using `meteor create my_project` first then import the project into Netbeans.

Comment: Thanks. Yes.  Within Netbeans,  New Project > from existing sources and I was able to have the option to find the files.